# Overloading streaming on the Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Please RTFM me if needed, as so far I may have been searching for the wrong things!

On the Arduino

```
 Serial << "sdf" << var;
```

works a treat (with streaming.h referenced), but

```
#if (CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD)
    Serial <<  F("Run Macro: ") << strMacro << "\n";
#endif
```

takes three lines and makes the code unreadable.

I'd like to say something along the lines of:

```
Debug(CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD) << F("Run Macro: ") << strMacro << "\n";
```

Is this possible? I'd be happier with:

```
Debug.set(CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD); Debug << F("Run Macro: ") << strMacro << "\n";
```

I'll worry about size after I've had a go at this!

Many thanks,
Glyn

Comment: The preprocessor would be compile-time, the other would not. You really want the slowdown?

Comment: Size is more important to me than speed, but readability (at this stage) trumps all - also I used the word happier when I meant 'just about happy'

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor would be compile-time, the other would not. You really want the slowdown?

Anyway, if you accept a slightly different syntax, we get pretty near to what you wanted while not giving up on eliminating the useless code at compile-time:

```
#define COND(cond, ...) ((void)((exp) && (__VA_ARGS__, 0)))
```

Use as

```
COND(CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD, Serial <<  F("Run Macro: ") << strMacro << "\n");
```

Or, if you only ever test that one condition:

```
#define IFDEBUG(...) ((void)((CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD) && (__VA_ARGS__, 0)))
```

Use as

```
IFDEBUG(Serial <<  F("Run Macro: ") << strMacro << "\n");
```

Comment: I like! Ended up using `#define COND(cond, ...) ((void)((CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & cond) && (__VA_ARGS__, 0)))`
 @deduplicator .  I hate using things I don't understand. __VA ARGS __ gets me the variadic args - what does the , 0 do?

Comment: I just put the 0 there so there is a value which can be cast to void, even if the last expression you provide is already of type void.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own class to do exactly that.

Comment: Could, but that would take reading up and would probably use memory - very limited on the Arduino. Thanks though.

Comment: But it seems to be debug only. Under release it would be compiled away to nothing.

Comment: Your right, but at the moment I don't know how to write a class that inherits for Serial. And if I do I don't know if I if newserial(doit) << "Thang"; is allowed grammer. I'm learning..

Answer (score 0):

I am answering only compile-time solution for the expression:

```
Serial << "sdf" << var;
```

Assume `Serial` is a global instance of class. Let's say instance of class `DebugWriter`. This class has overloaded `operator <<`. Now, you can make another class `FakeDebugWriter`, which will also have `operator <<` implemented, but that would do nothing. Further, you can declare `Serial` instance as:

```
#if CRIPWEB_DEBUG_BITS & DEBUG_CMD
DebugWriter Serial;
#else
FakeDebugWriter Serial;
#endif
```

But it should be noted that `Serial<<` will still make call to function in case of `FakeDebugWriter` - though compiler may omit out the function call.

Therefore, it would be better to write debug-logging as function-style macro only. You can craft the macro has do some thing (or something heavy), and another as Do-nothing.

EDIT: After comment from OP. Here is analogues similar example.

```
SmallInt a, b;
```

Where `SmallInt` would be type-defined, depending on value(s) of pre-processor macro (not macro macro).

```
#if SomeCondition
typedef int SmallInt;
#else
typedef short SmallInt;
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, but 5 lines rather than 3, I like to read easily readable code. That's why I'm taking your and Deduplicators suggestion and delving deeper into macro land. Ta!

Comment: Did you understand it? You would use `Serial<<xyz` anywhere. And that's just a single line, not 3 or 5 lines.

Comment: Aha, no I had not fully understood first time. However I use `#define HTTP_REQ_DEBUG       B10000000
#define MACRO_DEBUG          B01000000
#define RAMUSE_DEBUG         B00100000
#define IP_DEBUG    B00010000
#define DEBUG_CMD    B00001000
#define DEBUG_SEND      B00000100
#define DEBUG_TODO           B00000010
#define DEBUG_TEST           B00000001
`

Comment: Whoops, unreadable, sorry. However, then I use just the flags I want to minimize output clutter. Your solution is excellent but  global. I can see many uses for it in other ways.